# Node.Js Slack App Https request 'Uncaught Exception: Converting circular structure to JSON'

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, https, slack

I am trying to create a slack app, using [stdlib](https://stdlib.com/) that can take a simple text argument and then use that information to make an https request to a url and get a json response back. However, when I try to make this request and output the string to slack as a text response, I get the following error:

```
Critical Error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
at Domain.criticalExecution.run ([eval]:86:45)
at Domain.run (domain.js:242:14)
at callback ([eval]:66:23)
at func.index.apply.params.concat ([eval]:199:51)
at module.exports (/var/task/functions/commands/price.js:23:3)
at Domain.functionExecution.run ([eval]:197:22)
at Domain.run (domain.js:242:14)
at process.nextTick ([eval]:196:27)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
```

Now, I can't see anywhere in the response json that makes it cyclical, since it is just a text response, I don't add to it, so it confuses me.
Below is the source code:

```js
module.exports = (user, channel, text = '', command = {}, botToken = null, callback) => {

  callback(null, {
    response_type: 'in_channel',
    text: getString()
  });
};

  function getString() {
 return getNasaData('DEMO_KEY');
  }


function getNasaData(key = 'DEMO_KEY', callback) {
  return https.get({
    host: 'api.nasa.gov',
    path: '/planetary/apod?api_key=${key}'
  }, (response) => {
    let body = '';
    response.on('data', (data) => {
      body += data;
    });
    response.on('end', () => {
      let parsed = JSON.parse(body);
      callback({
       copyright: parsed.copyright,
       date: parsed.date
      });
    });
  });
};
```

I've looked around for solutions and its unclear what would cause this exception other than a cyclical reference. Perhaps it is to do with the callbacks I'm using in the two methods?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: you are getting response in text right?

Comment: Yes, the response, when I enter it into the address bar is text in json format:
[This is the URL in full](https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY)